# PHP/mySQL - concat query misses out a few fields

Tags: php, mysql

I've search forms on various webpages within my site which I've using to display the particular records from the database which the user is entering in the search text field.

I've been using the same code of course in all those pages with some modifications to the CONCAT SQL query & it has been working fine on all those pages except one.

Here's the query for that page -

```
if(isset($_POST['keywrd']))
{
    $kw1 = $_POST['keywrd'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `library_books` WHERE CONCAT(`Book_id`, `Book_Title`, `Author`, `Class`, `Subject`) LIKE '%$kw1%' limit $page1,18";
    $Result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $cou = mysqli_num_rows($Result);

        if(!$row = mysqli_fetch_array($Result))
        {
            echo "</br></br>";
            die("No match found! Please Try Again");
        }


 while($query_exec=mysqli_fetch_array($Result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
 {
  echo '<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
  <td height="auto"  width="70" align="center">'.$query_exec['Book_id'].'</td>
  <td height="auto"  width="300" align="center">
    <a name="status" href="status.php?id='.$query_exec['Book_id'].'"> '.$query_exec['Book_Title'].'</a>
</td>
  <td height="auto"  width="230" align="center">'.$query_exec['Author'].'</td>
  <td height="auto"  width="70" align="center">'.$query_exec['Class'].'</td>
  <td height="auto"  width="165" align="center">'.$query_exec['Subject'].'</td>
  <td height="auto"  width="120" align="center">'.$bool.'</td>
  <td height="auto"  width="180 align="center">'.$isava.'</td>
</tr></table>';
}
}
```

On this page, the query does return results based on the input provided, but it misses out a few fields which also matches the input keywords.

What could have possibly gone wrong?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data including the rows which are missed?

Comment: this is an online LMS, which keeps the records of various books.

For ex:- If I type "Phy" to search the books based on Physics available in the database, It only returns Physics Part 2 but not part 1.

Similar problem exists with other books as well.

Comment: If you remove the `limit` does it fix the problem? You could be skipping some records if `$page1` is more than 0 or you have more than 18 results.

Comment: I've tried it, but unfortunately it doesn't work, & also the system is in testing phase atm & only have almost 2 books of each subject available in it & the LIMIT is 18, so I don't think that would be the problem

Comment: I've copied the query from the sql page of the phpmyadmin module itself, it's running fine over there

Comment: `$page1` is set to 0 and not 1?

Comment: yes, the page indexing starts from 0

Comment: the same query is working fine on a different page but not here :(

Comment: Incidentally, LIMIT without ORDER BY is meaningless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're fetching the first row to check if there is a result and the while loop starts from the next row as [`mysqli_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) is an extended version of [`mysqli_fetch_row`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) which uses a pointer to keep track of the result set.

You should check `$cou` instead to see if your result was successful and remove the `if` statement all together or at a minimum reset the `$Result` using [`mysqli_data_seek`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php).

Check `$cou`:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `library_books` WHERE CONCAT(`Book_id`, `Book_Title`, `Author`, `Class`, `Subject`) LIKE '%$kw1%' limit $page1,18";
$Result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$cou = mysqli_num_rows($Result);

if ($cou < 1) {
    echo "</br></br>";
    die("No match found! Please Try Again");
}

while ($query_exec=mysqli_fetch_array($Result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
```

Reset the pointer:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `library_books` WHERE CONCAT(`Book_id`, `Book_Title`, `Author`, `Class`, `Subject`) LIKE '%$kw1%' limit $page1,18";
$Result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$cou = mysqli_num_rows($Result);

if (!$row = mysqli_fetch_array($Result)) {
    echo "</br></br>";
    die("No match found! Please Try Again");
}

mysqli_data_seek($Result, 0);

while ($query_exec=mysqli_fetch_array($Result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
```